# How to keep new <li> Elements on the top using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to add new `<li>` elements to the top (instead of at the bottom). I have come up with basic code which makes use of `document.appendChild()`. Since there is no `prependChild()` I couldn't figure out a way to get it done.

Here is the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/pwpSx/

Once you run it. All `<li>` elements appear as 0,1,2,3,4,5 . But, i want them to be displayed as

5,4,3,2,1,0 after all iterations are complete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use plain JavaScript.

```
list.insertBefore(li,list.firstChild);
```

Screw jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Node.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/insertBefore).

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RZRJq/)

```
var els = document.getElementById('els');
var counter = 0;
function newel() {
    var x = document.createElement('li');
    x.innerHTML = "This is really cool : " + counter;
    return x;
}
var si = setInterval(function() {
    els.insertBefore(newel(), els.firstChild);
    counter++;
    if(counter > 5) { 
        clearInterval(si);
    }
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if jquery is an option for you, but looks like you should be able to find the first li and then call insertBefore:

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

edit: Looking at the source for insertBefore, it looks nontrivial to implement.

Comment: I played with jquery. Looks like i have a solution here. http://jsfiddle.net/PCXZm/

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
var els = document.getElementById('els');
var counter = 5;
function newel() {
    var x = document.createElement('li');
    x.innerHTML = "This is really cool : " + counter;
    return x;
}
var si = setInterval(function() {
    //var cur = els.innerHTML;
    //els.firstChild = newel();
    els.appendChild(newel());
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) { // exit after few iterations
        clearInterval(si);
    }
},2000);
```

OR (Example)

```
   // Create The Element Dynamically. Here we are creating  Div   
   var ele=document.createElement("div");
   // Assume our Parent Element  ID is  container
   // So  function  goes like below 
   prependElement('container',ele)

   // ACTUAL  CODE 
   function prependElement(parentID,child)
    {
        parent=document.getElementById(parentID);
        parent.insertBefore(child,parent.childNodes[0]);
    }
```

Comment: He wants to add 0 first, not 5 first.  But when he adds 1, he then wants it to be 1,0.  Then when he adds 2: 2,1,0.

Comment: Actually its not about the numbers. but the order in which i recieve data. Think of it in terms of time. All future events should be displayed on top.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to implement it using raw JS, nut you could use jQuery which is the easiest way (IMO) to use JavaScript.
There are many functions to manipulate DOM which can be found here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use JQuery's [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function, then you can write your own implementation using just plain old Javascript. Another answer suggests using `insertBefore`, but I would advise against using this approach since it would require selecting the first `li` element instead of the list.

Here's a plain old Javascript solution:

```
function prepend(ListID, ListMarkup)
{
    var List = document.getElementByID(ListID);
    List.innerHTML = "<li>" + ListMarkup + "</li>" + List.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: I didn't wanted the innerHTML solution. So, searching for a DOM only one. Sorry, should've mentioned this in the question.